# Should I drain water after I cook noodles in microwave?

Tags: microwave, noodles

I have just cooked noodles in microwave. In some websites it says to drain water before eating it. Some doesn't say about draining water.

Should I drain the water as I have cooked it in microwave?

Comment: Hello SrikanthJeeva, and welcome to our site. We specialize in cooking only, and nutrition and healthiness of food is off topic for us. So I had to remove the part which asked about health consequences. The rest of the question is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you like your noodles swimming in water? If not, drain them.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what sort of noodles, but you could cook them with less water. If you cook the noodles with 'just enough' water it will all be absorbed during cooking, so there will be none left to drain.

This would probably be quicker, as there is less water for the microwave to heat up. Also, if the noodles have any sort of seasoning, draining the water could wash this away, so you would lose some flavour.

Comment: +1 - "Depends" is indeed the best answer. There are noodle recipes which require the noodles to remain in their cooking liquid, e.g. ramen soup.